# WordPress - add second logo to customizer

Tags: php, wordpress, underscores-wp

I want to add to my theme different logo that will be used on sticky header when user scrolls the page.

I tried to do it like here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/256985/185092

I edit Underscores theme so I added the code to customizer.php and the whole function looks like this:

```
function mytheme_customize_register( $wp_customize ) {
    $wp_customize->get_setting( 'blogname' )->transport         = 'postMessage';
    $wp_customize->get_setting( 'blogdescription' )->transport  = 'postMessage';
    $wp_customize->get_setting( 'header_textcolor' )->transport = 'postMessage';

    if ( isset( $wp_customize->selective_refresh ) ) {
        $wp_customize->selective_refresh->add_partial(
            'blogname',
            array(
                'selector'        => '.site-title a',
                'render_callback' => 'mytheme_customize_partial_blogname',
            )
        );
        $wp_customize->selective_refresh->add_partial(
            'blogdescription',
            array(
                'selector'        => '.site-description',
                'render_callback' => 'mytheme_customize_partial_blogdescription',
            )
        );
    }

    $wp_customize->add_setting('sticky_header_logo');
    $wp_customize->add_control(new WP_Customize_Image_Control($wp_customize, 'sticky_header_logo', array(
        'label' => 'Sticky Header Logo',
        'section' => 'title_tagline', 
        'settings' => 'sticky_header_logo',
        'priority' => 8 
    )));
}
add_action( 'customize_register', 'mytheme_customize_register' );
```

and in header.php I have:

```
            <div class="site-branding">
                <?php the_custom_logo(); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="site-branding-alternative">
                <?php get_theme_mod( 'sticky_header_logo' ) ?>
            </div>
```

I will use display none and block to show one logo or another but now css is not done so both logos should appear. The problem is, I have possibility to add the second logo in Appearance - Customize - Site identity but it is not shown on the page.

What did I do wrong?

edit:

```
<?php var_dump(get_theme_mods()); ?>
```

gave me such a code:

```
array(7) {
  [0]=>bool(false) 
  ["nav_menu_locations"]=>array(1) {
    ["menu-1"]=>int(2)
  }
  ["custom_css_post_id"]=>int(-1) 
  ["header_image"]=>string(75) "http://localhost/whites/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/cropped-header-image.png" 
  ["header_image_data"]=>object(stdClass)#1138 (5) {
    ["attachment_id"]=>int(15) ["url"]=>string(75) "http://localhost/whites/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/cropped-header-image.png" ["thumbnail_url"]=>string(75) "http://localhost/whites/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/cropped-header-image.png" ["height"]=>int(473) ["width"]=>int(1000)
  }
  ["custom_logo"]=>int(18) 
  ["sticky_header_logo"]=>string(63) "http://localhost/whites/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/logo-3-1.png"
}
```

Comment: Have you checked that your new logo is getting saved to the database? Or is the problem in the code retrieving it from the db? Knowing where the problem is happening is the first step to fixing it, so information about your debugging is important for us to know :)

Comment: The file has been uploaded to media library and on Site Identity panel I see two logos.

Comment: If you `var_dump(get_theme_mods());` do you see anything for your second logo in there?

Comment: It printed the code to the website. I will paste it in two parts because it's too long for a comment.

Comment: array(7) { [0]=> bool(false) ["nav_menu_locations"]=> array(1) { ["menu-1"]=> int(2) } ["custom_css_post_id"]=> int(-1) ["header_image"]=> string(75) "http://localhost/whites/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/cropped-header-image.png" ["header_image_data"]=> object(stdClass)#1138 (5) { ["attachment_id"]=> int(15) ["url"]=> string(75) "http://localhost/whites/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/cropped-header-image.png" ["thumbnail_url"]=>

Comment: string(75) "http://localhost/whites/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/cropped-header-image.png" ["height"]=> int(473) ["width"]=> int(1000) } ["custom_logo"]=> int(18) ["sticky_header_logo"]=> string(63) "http://localhost/whites/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/logo-3-1.png" }

Comment: You should add it to your question so it’s easier to read. Is there anything there for your custom changes? You will know that better than us, as you wrote the code :)

Comment: I added to question. ["sticky_header_logo"] which is on the end of this code points to the file logo-3-1.png which is the file that I uploaded as a second logo. So it looks ok and I have still no idea why it doesn't appear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now that we have gone through the problem step by step, we know the code in `customizer.php` is working because :

- `get_theme_mods`returns your logo file so the problem's not the database or theme mods.
- `var_dump` shows that the logo file is saved in the `sticky_header_logo` array key as expected.

**The problem:**

This means that the problem must be in `header.php` so we have narrowed down where to start looking for the coding problem. The marvels of debugging :) If we look at the code you are using to show the second logo:

```
<div class="site-branding-alternative">
    <?php get_theme_mod( 'sticky_header_logo' ) ?>
</div>
```

You are using the `get_theme_mod` to *get* the value of `sticky_header_logo` which is correct... but you are not *displaying* the result. This function doesn't output the logo in the same way that `the_custom_logo` does, it just returns the url.

**To fix the problem:**

You need to create the `<img>` tag using the url returned from `get_theme_mod` and echo it to the screen, e.g.:

```
<div class="site-branding-alternative">
    <?php 
    $sticky_logo_url = get_theme_mod( 'sticky_header_logo' );
    if ($sticky_logo_url )
       echo '<img src="'.$sticky_logo_url.'" alt = "logo alt test" class="sticky_logo_class">';
    ?>
</div>
```

**Reference:**

- [WP Code Reference for `get_theme_mod`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_theme_mod/)

Comment: Thank you for explanation :) In your code there is unnecessary closing } but without this, it works :)

Comment: @maja Oops, I forgot to remove that when I was tidying the code, I'll fix it now. Glad it helped! The most important skill for *any* developer is debugging, so I always try to explain how to debug the problem so it can help people know what to do next time... it can be a *very* tedious process, but *very* important! :)

Answer (score 2):

Use the hook to add a transparent logo uploader

```
add_action('customize_register', 'transparent_logo_customize_register');

function transparent_logo_customize_register($wp_customize){}
```

Inside the function you can add as many fields as you want

```
$wp_customize->add_setting('transparent_logo');
$wp_customize->add_control(new WP_Customize_Image_Control($wp_customize, 'transparent_logo', array(
    'label'    => __('Transparent Logo', 'store-front'),
    'section'  => 'title_tagline',
    'settings' => 'transparent_logo',
    'priority'       => 4,
)));
```